# How to implement "one time offer" consumable products in app

Tags: ios, swift2, in-app-purchase

I am developing app which have consumable and non-consumable products. Thats fine, but now I am thinking of implementing consumable product like "one time offer" which will be displayed for limited time. The point is I dont know how to implement that.

First, do I need my server for this product? How I display this product in game? etc..
Any tutorial will help.
Chears

Comment: This has less to do with programming and more with logic. You can make use of NSUserDefaults to set one time offer instance or sync the product with web server.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is best solutions for your question.
But, if you want to manage exact date (do not keep dependency on device date-time), you have to use server.

Comment: I was hoping for something without server. Those cosumable products would be displayed after submitting app...tnx for post

Comment: Using NSUserDefaults you can do.